# Fuzzy matching sentences to stanzas

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentence-similarity

I have lyrics from srt subtitle files. If I want to match them to stanzas from another lyrics website, what is the best approach to this?

My approach has been taking tf-idf vector each lyric line and trying to fuzzy match to the staza, using starting and end time of the lyric line as a clue to whether the line might belong to the previous stanzas, next stanzas, or belong to a stanzas of it's own.

I've also tried dynamic programming, but with less success. Due to the high variance in the structure of the lyrics and the stanza, sometimes the results come out completely shifted or messed up, especially if there are repeated chorus.

If there is a Recurrent Neural Networks or other Machine Learning algorithm, is there an existing approach to such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Doc2Vec or Word2Vec methods, basically you train a NN with some corpus, the NN will generate a vector for each word/document, those vectors will have similarity based on the similarty of words in the real world (corpus)

so vector of **love** and **care** will be very similar, those vectors hold some other cool properties like if yo subtract or add them you can get a word that posses some meaning of the substation or addition induce

once you will get the vector of words or docs you can check similarity between vectors with various methods, commonly used is the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

this method mixed with tf-idf to generate weights for best results

usage is very easy, for example

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import brown

b = Word2Vec(brown.sents())
print b.most_similar('money', topn=5)
```

output

```
[(u'care', 0.9145717024803162), (u'chance', 0.9034961462020874), (u'job', 0.8980690240859985), (u'trouble', 0.8751360774040222), (u'everything', 0.873866856098175)]
```

I suggest to take a look at [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)